# Loading data from Firebase asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, async-await

I am developing a business manager web app in React with Firebase back-end. I am also coding a local API to simplify Firebase functions. I created this method, which loads data from a Firebase collection and returns an array of documents.

```
getDocuments(collection) {
    var documents = [];

    firebase.firestore().collection(collection).get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            documents.push(doc);
        });
    }).then(() => {
        return documents;
    })
}
```

However, when I call the method and assign it to a variable which I later print to the console, it says `undefined`.

```
var employees = getDocuments("employees");
console.log(employees);
```

What I want to do is to use `.then()` after calling the method to print the already loaded data to the console. Something like this:

```
var employees = getDocuments("employees").then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getDocuments` function seems to be unnecessarily complicated. This:

```
   getDocuments(collection) {    
          return firebase.firestore().collection(collection).get().then(snapshot=>snapshot.docs)
    }
```

yields exactly the same intended result (an Array of docs wrapped in a promise) as your function but performs faster since it skips looping through all the documents in the snapshot https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs

Afterwards just extract the value from the Promise returned by this function in your preferred way:

**Option 1 (async/await)**

```
let employees= await getDocuments('employees')
console.log(employees)
```

**Option 2 (chaining)**

```
let employees =[] 
getDocuments('employees').then(response => {
    employees=response 
    console.log(employees) 
})
```

**Explanation**

When you are doing this:

```
var employees = getDocuments("employees").then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
```

you aren't receiving any value from getDocuments since you didn't return anything in the first place.

```
getDocuments(collection) {
    var documents = [];

    firebase.firestore().collection(collection).get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            documents.push(doc);
        });
    }).then(() => {
        return documents; <-- this is returning the value of documents to the parent scope which is 'getDocuments', since the 'then' is related to the 'get' function
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, works exactly as desired!

Comment: @Erninger Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `employees` in the `then` like this

```
var employees = [];
getDocuments("employees").then(response => {
    employees = response;
    console.log(response);
})
```

Or if you are in an asynchronous function, you could go for something like this

```
var employees = await getDocuments("employees");
console.log(employees);
```

But the `await` keyword has to be done in an `async` function

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with the original ```getDocument()``` function, since it does not return any ```Promise```. However, after adjusting the method, it works just fine! Thank you for your answer!